# phpinfo() not working correctly in HHVM

Tags: php, nginx, hhvm

I am running HHVM, and I am trying to output `phpinfo()`.

It outputs to the page the following:

> HipHop

Which isn't correct, even by the hhvm docs. What is going on here?

http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Then you've probably done something wrong, how can you expect us to guess what you've done though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is correct. HHVM doesn't output anything yet than "HipHop".

This was already reported 2010.

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/172

https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1038

You could use this to see what your configuration is https://gist.github.com/ck-on/67ca91f0310a695ceb65

Comment: That link is really useful, it's much better than just returning "HipHop".